# is there any way to create directory in data directory location of Amazon RDS PostgreSQL instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

AWS RDS PostgreSQL  instance able to connect from another PostgreSQL client but not able to see data directory and configuration files .is there any way to edit/view data directory and configuration files

Comment: No, it's a sealed system by design. Why would you want to?

Comment: I believe you can `select * from pg_settings` on RDS, no?

Comment: I would required to create empty data directory on  Amazon RDS PostgreSQL instance for my application

Comment: @Vao Tsun:Can we update postgresql.conf,pg_hba.conf files using postgres query?

Comment: no, you cant. I created answer for you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with file system, use `EC2` instances with postgres installed and configured as you wish. Neither postgres.conf, nor hba.conf cant be edited directly on file system. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.html#Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.Parameters

Instead use amazon provided interface to change supported parameters or use `SET` command where possible...